# Does Xcode have a "Generate Initializer" command similar to IntelliJ's "Generate Constructor"?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Aside from the generator for a struct's memberwise initilizer, does Xcode have a "Generate Initializer" command similar to IntelliJ's "Generate Constructor"? If not, is there a way to make one? I'm looking to speed up my dev process a bit.

Comment: Why does your question have both Objective-C and Swift in the tags? The answer is different depending on the language; which language are you interested in? Pick one, please.

Comment: I included both tags because, aside from the memberwise initializer generator for Swift, the problem is the same for generating an initializer in Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: The problem is not at all the same. An initializer in Objective-C is an elaborate thing, which must be exactly right, and woe betide whoever gets it wrong. As you rightly say, there is a refactoring command for generating the memberwise initializer for Swift. For Objective-C, no.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works in objective-c, but this works in Xcode with swift. If you right-click on the class name in its declaration, you can select refactor->generate memberwise initializer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C, just type `init` on a blank line somewhere at file scope within the `@implementation` and the autocomplete menu will offer some ready-made init method snippets. (This is just Xcode's general code snippets functionality. You can create your own snippets to work just like that.)